# Use or not to use multiple ips on the same network card?

Tags: networking, centos, ethernet

I got a Dell r620 that cames with 4 network interfaces.

If I have for example 4 ips, and want to assigne them to the server. What would be better, in terms of performance.

Add all the 4 ips to the same interface, or one for each one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely the answer is reasonably obvious. If you have (and configure) 4x 1Gb NIC's then you have the potential to attain 4 Gigabits Per Second of data throughput if all 4 IP addresses are hit hard.

If you configure all 4x IP's on one interface, then you can only ever get 1Gbps shared between them all.

There's nothing inherently wrong with having multiple IP's on one NIC, but if you can spread them across multiple physical interfaces, then there's absolutely no reason not to.

Comment: Well... I won't have that traffic, but thanks to you i decided to add one ip for each card. So in casse if one card fail, I wont loose access to the server. Thank you.